# SD_SCDS_CREATE cannot create with FKART

Tags: abap, bapi, function-module

I need to create a document cost with shipment type Z003 (requested by client). Whenever I give the FM the FKART = Z003 does not work. If I remove the parameter it works but creates it with Z001 type.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `Whenever I give the FM the FKART = Z003 does not work` what error does it throw?

Comment: Hmmm i don't remember exactly but i found i way of doing it with batch input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your customer system has some BAdI active that sets the value to `Z001`. Have you checked this one in function `SD_SCD_TYPE_DETERMINE`?

```
* BADI SCD_CREATE: SET_SHIPMENT_COST_TYPE
  CALL FUNCTION 'SD_SCD_GET_INSTANCE'
    EXPORTING
      i_badi          = co_badi_scd_create
    CHANGING
      c_interface_ref = l_badi_create
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS          = 1.
  IF sy-subrc IS INITIAL.
    CALL METHOD l_badi_create->set_shipment_cost_type
      EXPORTING
        i_refobj = i_refobj
      CHANGING
        c_fkart  = e_tvtf-fkart.
  ENDIF.
```